# Regular expression for remove metadata

Tags: .net, entity, connection-string

I trying to create a application with use some Entity Framework and some old DataSets but I only have a dynamic connection string using entity and need remove metadata at runtime to create a connection string to my database. Anyone know a way to remove all metadata from Entity Framework Connection

I have this

```
metadata=res://*/Models.SiteModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SiteModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SiteModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
```

and need only this:

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class:

```
string connectionString = "metadata=res://*/Models.SiteModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SiteModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SiteModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True\"";
EntityConnectionStringBuilder builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
builder.Metadata = null;
connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Very nice, its more easy ways. You saved my day ;)

Comment: Helped me a lot! Much simpler than trying to write a Regex to extract the info.
Also used as @pedrofernandes mentioned in his answer to use `builder.ProviderConnectionString`

Answer (score 5):

A better property to use is `builder.ProviderConnectionString` rather than stripping the Metadata from the builder to get `build.ConnectiongString`.

Comment: Yeah, and where does this builder variable come from. Your answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but posting for others.

```
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionInApp.Config"].ConnectionString;

    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnectionStringBuilder = new System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);
    string databaseName = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog;
```